# How to add a new view to Apple's AVCam Example

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been trying to add a new view (as a flip side view) but couldn't manage to do that.
I am aware that the example doesn't have an appdelagate. so in order to do that, what should I do?

Thanks in advance..

PS: here is the [code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AVCamViewController.m file, look for viewDidLoad method.  You can adjust your capture video preview area and add another of your own view.

Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// ...
[newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];  //adjust camera preview area to accommodate your new view.
UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 210, 200, 50)];  //either a UIImageView or UIView
[self.view addSubview:myView];  //add your view to the main view

//....
}
```